Gradle Dependency Issue: Duplicate class xxx found in modules A and xx.jar
Getting error :

Duplicate class xxx found in modules A and xx.jar.
I need to add 2 libraries, out of which one is dependency library and other is added dependency as jar.
Library internally uses the files present in jar but performs different functionality but the class name is same.
Both library individually works good. Since both have different functionality specified in there library, I cant exclude any of dependency module or say library/dependency.

Error I get while running the project
I have added

android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
Tried invalidating the cache and rebuilding, still get same error


If the classes have different functionality you have to decide which one to use. You should at least talk to the developers of both projects and ask why they use the same class names. For more details we would need to know the class names and the libraries they belong to but as you have redacted them...
